# How do you change the form background color?

Tags: c#

I need to know how to change the form backcolor.  In the button click event, I have this.BackColor = SystemColors...

How should this part be written for, say, the color blue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the code below.

```
this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

This is a struct contained in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

You may want to take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktb99cf2.aspx)

Comment: This helped a ton, sorry about the simple question I couldn't find the Color.Blue. Kind of sucks that I can't ask questions any more though. Am I just stuck this way forever?

Comment: You'll need to import the System.Drawing namespace. add a declaration to the top of your file. using System.Drawing;